# Exchange 2013 unable to receive mail from internet and internally after installing Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, exchange-2013

After checking on
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

i am getting the error

The server returned status code 451 - Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX2

and I've tested everything and it seems to be okay including the DNS and everything.
I am suspecting this may be due to the new virtual adapter created by Hyper-V since now all the data is routed through it.

But every setting on the Virtual adapter matches with one i had on my physical adapter.

What might i be missing here?

Comment: 1) Why don't you remove the virtual adapter installed by Hyper-V and check if the server works? 2) any detailed error in the Event Log? 3) Googling your error codes returned this, sounds promising although I don't have more details about your environment: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/11/22/exchange-2013-dns-settings-cause-transport-services-to-crash/